# PLINK meta-analysis method

Tags: p-value, meta-analysis, genetics

I am trying to determine exactly what method [PLINK](http://pngu.mgh.harvard.edu/~purcell/plink/) uses for meta-analysis. I can't find it in the program documentation/FAQ anywhere. Inverse variance? (given the meta command only requires effect size and SE)? ALso, what method its using to generate a P-value?

Answer (score 1):

the Plink method used for meta-analyses is indirectly described here:

https://www.cog-genomics.org/plink/1.9/postproc

"weighted-z' requests weighted Z-score-based p-values (as computed by the Abecasis Lab's METAL software) ****in addition to PLINK's usual inverse variance-based analysis.**** This requires P and effective sample size fields (default column names are 'P' and 'NMISS'; these can be changed with --meta-analysis-p-field and --meta-analysis-ess-field). Note that, if the numbers of cases and controls are unequal, effective sample size should be 4 / (1/<# of cases> + 1/<# of controls>)."